# ¿Cómo recuperar el data attribute de un id de dos selects? jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

Quiero recuperar el *data attribute* de un `id` de dos `select` pero siempre sale el primero (`formats`).

Este es mi código:

```
<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list"
    id="selector-list" data-level="formats" ></select>

<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list"
    id="selector-list" data-level="families"></select>
```

*jQuery*:

```
var level = $('.selector-list-viversita-formats').attr('data-level');
```

Comment: El atributo `id` tiene que tener un valor único para cada elemento. Si cumples con el estándar HTML, debes poner un ID distinto a cada select

Comment: Y como puedo saber cual estoy seleccionando?

Comment: obteniendo su id por `$('.selector-list-viversita-formats').attr('id');`

Answer (score 4):

Cualquier consulta que hagas al DOM, los elementos se devuelven en el orden en el que se encuentran, empezando desde el inicio del documento:

```js
$('.selector-list').each((i,elem) => {
  let data = $(elem).data('level');
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list" data-level="formats"></select>

<select name="selector-list" class="selector-list" data-level="families"></select>
```

Si te fijas he borrado el atributo id del select porque no estaba aportando nada: ambos tenían el mismo valor, lo cual es *ilegal* según el estándar de HTML.